# How to map a function to the value parts of rules

Tags: list-manipulation, rule

I want to map the function to the value part of these rules and get the following result:

```
{1 -> f[1, 2], 2 -> f[2, 3], 3 -> f[3, 4], 4 -> f[4, 5], 5 -> f[5, 6],
  6 -> f[6, 7], 7 -> f[1, 8], 8 -> f[8, 9], 9 -> f[9, 10], 
 10 -> f[10, 11], 11 -> f[11, 12], 12 -> f[7, 12], 13 -> f[2, 8], 
 14 -> f[3, 9], 15 -> f[4, 10], 16 -> f[5, 11], 17 -> f[6, 12], 
 18 -> f[2, 9], 19 -> f[3, 10], 20 -> f[5, 10], 21 -> f[6, 11]}
```

But I can't implement the requirements by the following ways：

```
pole = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {1, 8}, {8, 
        9}, {9, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {7, 12}, {2, 8}, {3, 9}, {4, 
        10}, {5, 11}, {6, 12}, {2, 9}, {3, 10}, {5, 10}, {6, 11}};
Map[f, Thread[Range[Length[pole]] -> pole], {2}]
```

What can I do to meet this requirement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> f @@ # &, pole]
```

> ```
> {1 -> f[1, 2], 2 -> f[2, 3], 3 -> f[3, 4], 4 -> f[4, 5], 5 -> f[5, 6],
>    6 -> f[6, 7], 7 -> f[1, 8], 8 -> f[8, 9], 9 -> f[9, 10], 
>    10 -> f[10, 11], 11 -> f[11, 12], 12 -> f[7, 12], 13 -> f[2, 8], 
>    14 -> f[3, 9], 15 -> f[4, 10], 16 -> f[5, 11], 17 -> f[6, 12], 
>    18 -> f[2, 9], 19 -> f[3, 10], 20 -> f[5, 10], 21 -> f[6, 11]}
> ```

Also

```
MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, f @@@ pole]

Thread[Range[Length[pole]] -> f @@@ pole]

Normal @ f @@@ AssociationThread[Range[Length[pole]], pole] 

rules = Thread[Range[Length[pole]] -> pole];
Normal @ f @@@ Association @ rules

MapAt[Apply[f], rules, {All, 2}]
```